# XML Input limit results with XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt

First let me start I am just taking a stab at XML and have no formal training so this may be a very basic question but it is oblivious for me.

I have an XML file that looks similar to this.

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <document>
          <properties>
            <basic>
              <property id="number">
                <value>305</value>
              </property>
              <property id="first">
                <value>given</value>
              </property>
              <property id="last">
                <value>family</value>
              </property>
           </basic>
          </properties>
        </document>
```

I then need to show with XML an output similar to this.

```
<document>
      <properties>
        <basic>
          <property id="number">
            <value>305</value>
          </property>
          <property id="last">
            <value>family</value>
          </property>
       </basic>
      </properties>
    </document>
```

Where I am just including certain property id values to the final destination.

I have been able to do this with CSV but not with XML being the output and not sure where I should start.

Example XSL that gives me a , deliminator value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="preg" match="property" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">


    <!-- Item 1 Value -->
    <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','number')">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Item 2 Value -->
    <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','last')">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for any suggestions you may have as I this is not my full time job doing these type of things. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the desired outcome with the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet, a *Blacklist approach*. This solution just omits certain (the blacklisted) elements and copies the rest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="property[@id='first']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is a combination of the *Identity template* and an empty template assuring that the matched elements are *not copied*.

---

The other approach is a *Whitelist approach*. It masks all `property` elements and then only copies the one's defined in the copy template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <!-- Omit all 'property' elements... -->
    <xsl:template match="property" />

    <!-- ...except for those with an @id of 'number' or 'last' -->
    <xsl:template match="property[@id='number' or @id='last']">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result in both cases is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>
      <property id="number">
        <value>305</value>
      </property>
      <property id="last">
        <value>family</value>
      </property>
    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

Comment: Thank you I will give both of those a try in the AM.