# Formatting results with XSLT file

Tags: xslt

I am a total XSL Newbie so please forgive if this is a simple question. I have looked but not found anything that has worked for me so far.

My previous post has gotten me this far. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290890/xml-input-limit-results-with-xslt-file) And some times has passed so have to learn again. =)

I am trying to build upon it with more changes to the XSL template which will dynamically change the 1st entry based on what is seen in the raw XML provided.

Example Data coming in looks like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>
      <property id="Types">
        <value>Documents</value>
      </property>
      <property id="name">
        <value>File_Name</value>
      </property>
      <property id="Number">
        <value>2989389389893</value>
      </property>
      <property id="Date">
        <value>1/13/2022</value>
      </property>
      <property id="latestDocType">
        <value>PDF</value>
      </property>
    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

Currently I am getting something like this as output

```
<FORM>
   <Types>Documents</Types>
   <Number>2989389389893</Number>
   <name>File_Name.PDF</name>
</FORM>
```

Using this XML Template I was able to achieve the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"></xsl:output>
<xsl:key name="preg" match="property" use="@id"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="FORM">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','Types')">
            <xsl:element name="Types">
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','Number')">
            <xsl:element name="Number">
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:element name="name">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','name')">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('preg','latestDocType')">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">.</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I am looking for is 'Types' to actually replace 'FORM' This way depending on what ever document type gets sent in as the 'Type' it will change according for backend software.

Something like this

```
<Documents>
   <Types>Documents</Types>
   <Number>2989389389893</Number>
   <name>File_Name.PDF</name>
</Documents>
```

Or

```
<Photos>
   <Types>Photos</Types>
   <Number>2989389389893</Number>
   <name>File_Name.PDF</name>
</Photos>
```

the .... will be removed in final once I have everything working correctly.

Comment: You say you want to replace the root element name with whatever is contained in the Types element. But can there be multiple Types? Your use of multiple for-each instructions in your transform gives the impression that you are dealing with multiple Documents or Photos in the same input file?

Comment: Don't use disable-output-escaping unless you're an expert. When you become an expert, you'll know that you almost never need it. In your case it's pure noise because there is nothing to be escaped, therefore no need to disable it.

Comment: Also don't use `xsl:element` when the name (and the namespace) of the element is already known.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly even simpler using only:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:variable name="property" select="properties/basic/property" />
    <xsl:element name="{$property[@id='Types']/value}">
        <Number>
            <xsl:value-of select="$property[@id='Number']/value"/>
        </Number>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="$property[@id='name']/value"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$property[@id='latestDocType']/value"/>
        </name>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here the `Types` element is already removed.
The same caveat regarding the value of the `Types` property applies.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you want to do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:element name="{properties/basic/property[@id='Types']/value}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="properties/basic/property[@id='Types' or @id='name' or @id='Number']"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:element name="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property[@id='name']">
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../property[@id='latestDocType']/value"/>
    </name>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or (preferably):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:variable name="property" select="properties/basic/property" />
    <xsl:element name="{$property[@id='Types']/value}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$property[@id='Types' or @id='name' or @id='Number']"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:element name="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property[@id='name']">
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../property[@id='latestDocType']/value"/>
    </name>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this will fail if any of the values used for element names is not a valid XML element name.